# Determination of $(a,b)$ in Definite Integral.

Tags: integration

> Determine all $a,b>0$ for which $\displaystyle \int_{\frac {\pi}{6}}^{\frac {\pi}{3}}{}\frac{(\tan{x})^{\cot{x}}}{(\tan{x})^{a\cot{x}}+(\cot{x})^{b\tan{x}}}dx=\frac {\pi}{12}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$I=\displaystyle \int_{\frac {\pi}{6}}^{\frac {\pi}{3}}{}\frac{(\tan{x})^{\cot{x}}}{(\tan{x})^{a\cot{x}}+(\cot{x})^{b\tan{x}}}dx..........(1)$$

Now Using Property $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I =  \int_{\frac {\pi}{6}}^{\frac {\pi}{3}}{}\frac{(\cot{x})^{\tan{x}}}{(\cot{x})^{a\tan{x}}+(\tan{x})^{b\cot{x}}}dx..........(2)$$

Now How can I solve after that, Thanks

Comment: What is the source of the nice problem?

Comment: Only $1,1$ i think

Comment: Yes good point lab bhattacharjee

Comment: Clearly $a=1$ is a solution. But not sure about the uniqueness

Comment: actually I have taken from Aops.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar But id we put a and b equals to 1,1. then Will not answer be $\pi /4$